# SEM: parametric modelling of latent variances

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, structural-equation-modeling

I was reading [Mader et al. 2023](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.2212154120), where they model the effect of a variable (neuroticism) on both the outcome's (negative emotion) mean and variance. I noticed that the way the neuroticism score is obtained is by taking the mean of the scale items. Whether or not that is a reasonable choice here, I am aware of objections against ignoring the ordinal nature of measurements (e.g. [Liddell and Kruschke 2017](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2692323)).

I also know that most modern SEM tools support modelling ordinal responses (I'm familiar with lavaan and Stata's GSEM). However, I don't know of tools which also support placing predictors on the variance of endogenous variables.

So far I have been able to find approaches developed in the context of measurement invariance (see LSEM and MFA in [Hildebrandt et al. 2016](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00273171.2016.1142856)) and I know that scale-location transformations that apply uniformly over all measures of a given factor are statistically indistinguishable from scale-location transformations of the factor itself so I believe that modelling such dependencies should be possible at least in principle.

My question is simply whether there is any SEM software out there that supports simultaneous estimation of the usual SEM parameters with added parametric dependencies in the variances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is simply whether there is any SEM software out there that supports simultaneous estimation of the usual SEM parameters with added parametric dependencies in the variances.

Check out Bauer's work (with several colleagues) on parameter moderation, often called the "MNLFA" model, although it goes beyond mere factor analysis:

- https://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2014.889594
- https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1037/met0000077
- https://doi.org/10.1080/10705511.2019.1642754

Their examples are typically in M*plus* and SAS, but you can also use the R package `OpenMx`.  Here is an open-access tutorial: https://doi.org/10.1037/met0000501

Comment: Great, thank you for sharing these resources!